# Form array to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array and a variable:

```
const a = [1, 5, 3]
const model = 'Audi'
```

I want on object like that:

```
const obj = {
    data: {
      0: 1,
      1: 5,
      2: 3,
    },
    cars: {
      0: 'Audi',
      1: 'Audi',
      2: 'Audi',
    },
  }
```

I can I do that?

I think I can use a for. This is what I think to do:

```
const obj = {}
for(let i = 0; i < a.lenght; i++) {
  obj.cars = 
}
```

I don't know ho to complete the code... and I don't think is the best solution.

Thanks

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: use `forEach` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Object.assign` with spread syntax and `map` method.

```js
const a = [1, 5, 3]
const model = 'Audi'

const obj = {
  data: Object.assign({}, ...a.map((e, i) => ({[i]: e}))),
  cars: Object.assign({}, ...a.map((e, i) => ({[i]: model})))
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, a different approach could be with reduce and comma expression.

```js
const a = [1, 5, 3];
const model = 'Audi';

const create = (arr, model) => 

  arr.reduce((acc, val, i) =>
    
    // comma expression which evaluates from left to right and returns the last value
    
    (acc.data[i] = val, acc.model[i] = model, acc), { data: {}, model: {}});

console.log(create(a, model));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 const myArray = [1, 5, 3];
 const model = 'Audi';
 var obj = {};
 obj.data = {};
 obj.cars = {};
 var i = 0;
myArray.forEach(function(element){
i++;
obj.data[i] = element; 
obj.cars[i] = model;
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You could take two different variables which are later properties of the wanted object and use the array for assigning to an object and map `model` to an array and assign this to an object.

Both assignings keeps the indices as keys for the new object.

```js
var a = [1, 5, 3],
    model = 'Audi',
    data = Object.assign({}, a),
    cars = Object.assign({}, a.map(_ => model)),
    result = { data, cars };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a loop to set new const "final" (primitive way)
But I think @nenad's version is better.

```js
const a = [1, 5, 3];
const model = 'Audi';
const final = {};
var cars = [], data = [];
for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
    data.push(i);  cars.push(model);
}

final.data = data;
final.cars = cars;

console.log(final);
```